# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," in app.js file

Tags: reactjs

i am having this "parsing error in my app.js file. I have tried looking for what could have caused the error but i can't seem to see anything.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

import Movie from './components/Movie';

const FEATURED_API ="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&page=1";
const IMG_API = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280";
const SEARCH_API = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?&api_key=04c35731a5ee918f014970082a0088b1&query=";

function App() {
    const [ movies, setMovies ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(FEATURED_API)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setMovies(data.results);
        });
    }, []);

    return <div>{movies.length > 0 && 
            movies.map((movie) => <Movie />)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you tried to one line your movies.map function ? Like so : <div>{movies.length > 0 && movies.map((movie) => <Movie />)}</div>;

Comment: `movies.map((movie) => <Movie />` - there is mismatch in this line

Comment: Exactly on which line error occur?

Comment: @Newton, it seems there are no errors but still it's better to follow best practice and test...

return (
    <div>
      {movies.length > 0 &&
        movies.map((movie, index) => <Movie key=`movie_${index}`/>)}
    </div>
  );

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
function App() {
    const [ movies, setMovies ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(FEATURED_API)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setMovies(data.results);
        });
    }, []);

    return <div>{movies.length > 0 && 
            movies.map((movie) => <React.Fragment key={index}>{movie}</React.Fragment>)}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I guess he is not trying to render 'movie' but 'Movie' which he imported in second line from top.

Answer (score 0):

There are few points which has to be corrected

```
return <div>{movies.length > 0 && 
            movies.map((movie) => <Movie />)}</div>;
```

1. It is good practice to enclose the return statement in function bracket.
2. Instead of rendering a component you have just added one condition. It should be like this

   ```
   return (
       <div>
       {movies.length > 0 ?
               movies.map(movie => <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>) :null}
       </div>
       );
   ```